# cannot move out of a captured variable in an async `Fn` closure

Tags: asynchronous, rust, websocket, closures, ownership

Here is my code. In this program, I want to create a simple websocket server. When user sends a request to the `ws://{url}/`, the browser will establish a websocket connection with the server.

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::Arc};

use async_std::{prelude::*, sync::Mutex};
use tide_websockets::WebSocket;
use uuid::Uuid;

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    let connections = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
    let mut app = tide::new();
    app.at("/").get(WebSocket::new(move |_, mut stream| async move {
        let uuid = Uuid::new_v4();

        // Add the connection to clients when opening a new connection
        connections.lock().await.insert(uuid, stream.clone());

        // Waiting for the connection to be closed
        while let Some(Ok(_)) = stream.next().await {}

        // Remove the connection from clients when it is closed
        connections.lock().await.remove(&uuid);

        Ok(())
    }));

    // app.bind(url).await
}
```

When I tried to compile this program, the rustc said:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `connections`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:11:57
   |
9  |       let connections = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
   |           ----------- captured outer variable
10 |       let mut app = tide::new();
11 |       app.at("/").get(WebSocket::new(move |_, mut stream| async move {
   |  ____________________________________--------------------_^
   | |                                    |
   | |                                    captured by this `Fn` closure
12 | |         let uuid = Uuid::new_v4();
13 | |
14 | |         // Add the connection to clients when opening a new connection
15 | |         connections.lock().await.insert(uuid, stream.clone());
   | |         -----------
   | |         |
   | |         variable moved due to use in generator
   | |         move occurs because `connections` has type `Arc<async_std::sync::Mutex<HashMap<Uuid, WebSocketConnection>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...  |
23 | |         Ok(())
24 | |     }));
   | |_____^ move out of `connections` occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `mre` due to previous error
```

And this is the definition of the `Websocket::new` method (no sure if it's useful):

```rust
impl<S, H, Fut> WebSocket<S, H>
where
    S: Send + Sync + Clone + 'static,
    H: Fn(Request<S>, WebSocketConnection) -> Fut + Sync + Send + 'static,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<()>> + Send + 'static,
{
    /// Build a new WebSocket with a handler function that
    pub fn new(handler: H) -> Self {
        Self {
            handler: Arc::new(handler),
            ghostly_apparition: PhantomData,
            protocols: Default::default(),
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

I tried searching this problem before posting this question. Most of the answers are either irrelevant, or need to modify the source code of the method (`Websocket::new` method here). But this method is not written by me but is from a third-party crate. Is there still any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: What line in your example matches line `70` in the error message?

Comment: Please provide a [MRE]. The variable `stream`, for example, doesn't even exist in your code. We can't help you if the shown code doesn't actually produce the error message you claim it does.

Comment: @Finomnis  Sorry for the ambiguity of the description and code of my question. Now I have rewritten the question with a minimal reproducible example. Thanks!

Comment: @Esdeseserdt I haved updated the code with a minimal reproducible example to make this question more clear. The previous line 70 corresponds to line 24 `}));`, which is the end of the closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of `WebSocket::new()` has to be an `Fn` closure, meaning, it must be callable repeatedly.

In your code, however, it internally uses the `connections` variable inside of an `async move`, meaning it moves the variable into the `async` block. This can for obvious reasons only be done once.

It's easy to fix, though. Instead of moving the entire `connections` variable in, you need to create a new `Arc` reference of the `connections` variable and move that one into the `async move`. So every invocation gets its own copy of it, making it compatible with `Fn`.

Here is a compiling version:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::Arc};

use async_std::{prelude::*, sync::Mutex};
use tide_websockets::WebSocket;
use uuid::Uuid;

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    let connections = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
    let mut app = tide::new();
    app.at("/").get(WebSocket::new(move |_, mut stream| {
        let connections = Arc::clone(&connections);
        async move {
            let uuid = Uuid::new_v4();

            // Add the connection to clients when opening a new connection
            connections.lock().await.insert(uuid, stream.clone());

            // Waiting for the connection to be closed
            while let Some(Ok(_)) = stream.next().await {}

            // Remove the connection from clients when it is closed
            connections.lock().await.remove(&uuid);

            Ok(())
        }
    }));

    // app.bind(url).await
}
```